# heat equation problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a rectangular plate, of size $d$ in the $y$ direction
and size in the $x$ direction. At $y = d$ the temperature is held fixed at $f(x)$. On all other sides the plate's temperature is held at $0$. The plate is initially $0$, everywhere. Solve $\frac{du}{dt}= K\delta(u)$

$0 \le x \le L$

$0 \le y \le d$

$u(0,y,t) = 0$

$u(L,y,t) = 0$

$u(x,0,t) = 0$

$u(x,d,t) = f(x) = -2 \sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right) + \sin\left(3\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)$

$u(x,y,0) = 0$

I'm using heat equation:

$$u(x,t) =\sum b\sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right) e^{\left(-\Large\frac{kn\pi x}{L}\right)^2 \Large t}$$

and $$b = \frac{2}{L}\int f(x)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) dx$$

$$b(1) = \frac{2}{L}\int -2\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) dx $$

for $b(1)$

I got $$ \frac{2}{L}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right)\left(2\cos(\frac{2\pi x}{L}-1\right) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

How do you determine the expansion in terms of a sum for $b$?

for instance $b = \frac{1}{\pi}\sum (1- (-1)^n)$

then evaluate y at $0 \le y \le d$

determine $b(2)$

$b = b(1)+b(2)$

Is there an easier way to solve it?